# Calculating "area" of probability of density function (pdf)

Tags: probability

I have a piecewise equation of a probability of density function  like this:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{x}{6} + k, & \text{for } 0\le x \le 3, \\ \\0, & \text{for } x < 0 \lor x > 3 \end{cases}$$

I have to find k. To solve this I do

$$\frac{width * height}{2} = 1$$

$$\frac{3*(\frac{3}{6}+k)}{2} = 1$$
$$\frac{3}{2}+3k = 2$$
$$\frac{3}{2}+3k = 2$$
$$\frac{6k}{2} = 2 - \frac{3}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{6} = k$$

I tried in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3*((3%2F6)%2Bx))%2F2%20%3D%201) and I get the same result.

However, by schoolbook says the right answer is $$\frac{1}{12}$$

What am I doing wrong?$$\\$$
Please keep you answers somewhat basic. I haven't learnt about integral functions yet, or anything that involves this $\int_{}$ symbol .

Also, there is no more information to this problem. The function is all my book gives me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you impose $\frac{width * height}{2} = 1$ ?

That's incorrect. What you know is that the area below the graph of $f(x)$ must be $1$. The formula above corresponds to the area of a triangle. But your density $f(x)$ does not form a triangle, but a trapezium, with heights $f(0)=k$ and $f(3)=k+1/2$ (sketch a graph if you don't see this)

Can you go on from here?

Comment: I forgot that these could also be trapeziums. I could solve it using the formula for the trapezium. Additionally, I also learnt that I can use this formula when the shape is a triangle as well, which is useful because I might now know what the graph looks like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The height is the average height at the endpoints. (of the non-zero portion)

$(k + (k+\frac 36))\frac 12$

And the area the equals $3k + \frac 34 = 1$